# Misunderstanding idea of docker - where are benefits

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, docker

I can't understand where are benefits of docker. I come across with great praise in honor of `Docker`. It is **lightweight**, it very fast in comparison to virtual machine.

Can anyone explain me why docker can work without the whole stuff which is crucial for virtual machine ?  After all, in docker we have only kernel.  Yes, it is lightweight but software if very poor. Something beyond `ls, cp, cd,..` we have ?  In other case we need more software and consequently size of docker also may be huge.
Where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers are used to isolate that service that you run in it from the rest of the system. In that sense, they don't differ from a VM (Virtual Machine).

You have to install the service you need, e.g. mysql, in the container. This doesn't differ from using a VM, except that in a VM you also have to install the operating system. So there is a huge size benefit to Docker (often several GB).

When you run a single serve in a Docker container, you don't need all the packages a full operating system comes with. You just install what you need to run your service.

The Dockerfile that you use to create your container specifies exactly what you want to have installed in your container. You can add anything to it you want, the same way you would add packages to your server or desktop system.

When you create a new container Docker also 'reuses' existing containers that use the same base-container. Your first container may, for instance, occupy 300MB, but subsequent containers with the same base-containers may use as little as a few MB.
If you create two identical or similar VMs, they will always be full-size.

[This article on the Docker site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/) explains how docker images and containers are built.

For the reason Docker containers can do without a full operating system see https://serverfault.com/q/755607/388193